# How to make one of the fields in PFSignupViewController optional

Tags: ios, objective-c, parse-platform

I'm using [this tutorial](https://parse.com/tutorials/login-and-signup-views#default-signupdelegate) to set up the signup view of my Parse app, and I want to make use of `additionalField`, except I want it to be an optional field. The way that `MySignUpViewController` checks to make sure all the fields are filled before submitting is like so:

```
// Sent to the delegate to determine whether the sign up request should be submitted to the server.
- (BOOL)signUpViewController:(PFSignUpViewController *)signUpController shouldBeginSignUp:(NSDictionary *)info {
    BOOL informationComplete = YES;

    // loop through all of the submitted data
    for (id key in info) {
        NSString *field = [info objectForKey:key];
        if (!field || !field.length) { // check completion
            informationComplete = NO;
            break;
        }
    }

    // Display an alert if a field wasn't completed
    if (!informationComplete) {
        [[[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Missing Information" message:@"Make sure you fill out all of the information!" delegate:nil cancelButtonTitle:@"ok" otherButtonTitles:nil] show];
    }

    return informationComplete;
}
```

This means that it loops through all the fields and requires them all to have something in them to move onto the next step. How can I tell that loop to ignore `additionalField` when looping?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The goal is to make informationComplete = YES. To do this you can do something like:

```
// loop through all of the submitted data
for (id key in info) {
    if (![key isEqualToString:@"KEYTOIGNORE"]) { //IF the key is not equal to specified string continue execution
        NSString *field = [info objectForKey:key];
        if (!field || !field.length) { // check completion
            informationComplete = NO;
            break;
         } 
    }
}
```

This will prevent from checking the field you want to ignore to see if it is empty. So just figure out what it's key is and give it a go. Let me know how it goes, good luck!

Comment: Makes total sense and worked perfectly, thank you! Turns out the key was "additional", for anyone else who tries to do this.